# Add log or ln regression

Tags: logging, regression

I want to know if i can add log or ln only for some variables in my regression, to reduce mean and min max ?
I find some economics articles add log only for some variables but not for all variables in the regression!
It's really confusing for me
Is that's possible?
Thanks